# Difference between 兴趣 vs 意思?

Tags: difference

我对养宠物没有兴趣.

养宠物没有意思.

When to use one over the other? Don't they mean the same thing?

兴趣 definition is

> Interest (directed towards, not inherent in something).

What does that even mean?

Comment: RE: the definition - "Interest (directed towards [a thing], not inherent in something)" ... This means the speaker personally is not interested in "this thing/topic," but their lack of interest is not a comment on the intrinsic/inherent interest/value/qualities of "the thing/topic". ... It's the difference between saying "I don't personally have any interest in basketball," vs. "basketball [itself] is not interesting."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this context

- 没有兴趣 means "has no interest"  or "not interested" (not something you like to do or care about)
- 没有意思 means "meaningless", if something is meaningless to you, it is a given that you are not interested in it.

The implied meaning in the sentence "养宠物没有意思" is  "对我來説, 养宠物没有什么意思." (To me, keeping pet is meaningless)

Look at it the other way:

这玩意很**有趣** This stuff is very **interesting**

我对这玩意**很有兴趣** I am **very interested** in this stuff

这玩意**很有意思** This stuff is **very meaningful** (therefore, your are **interested** in it)

> *When to use one over the other?*

- When you say "没有兴趣" (I am not interested), you are expressing your personal preference about a topic, e.g. 'you may not like fishing, but you are not saying fishing is boring'
- When you say "没有意思" (meaningless to me), you are giving your low opinion on the topic, e.g. 'you really think fishing is waste of time'

Answer (score 2):

As a complement to Tang Ho's answer,

我对养宠物没有兴趣. (I'm **not interested in** keeping a pet.)

养宠物没有意思. (Keeping a pet is **not interesting**. Or, Keeping a pet is **not attractive** to me.)